# Pure Java Video Format without native Libraries

Tags: java, video

is there something like a video format/codec/container that works in java without the use of any native libraries?

i know there is that java media framework, but it seems a bit outdated.

Answer (score 3):

[Cortado](http://www.flumotion.net/cortado/) streaming applet distributes a theora codec written in java. It is also part of FMJ.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source library called JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ) that implements a couple of popular formats and codec in pure java. These include: H.264 ( AVC ), MPEG 1/2, Apple ProRes and JPEG. Formats include: MP4, Matroska, MPEG PS and MPEG TS.
The documentation is virtually non-existent though.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Criticism_and_alternatives) about the JMF.